# Learning Ruby on rails and getting excon SSL errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, excon

I have tried researching this, and have no idea where to even look in my application to fix this error. I have been taking a course on Udemy and I am trying to use Google Cloud storage to upload images. When I add an image into a new record and try to save I receive this error.

> SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError) Unable to verify certificate.
>
> This may be an issue with the remote host or with Excon. Excon has certificates bundled, but these can be customized.`Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_path] = path_to_certs`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_DIR'] = path_to_certs`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_ca_file] = path_to_file`, `ENV['SSL_CERT_FILE'] = path_to_file`, `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_callback] = callback` (see OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext#verify_callback), or `Excon.defaults[:ssl_verify_peer] = false` (less secure).

Comment: Figured this out! I specified an older version of excon in my gemfile. Seems like the newest version doesn't play nice with Windows. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. I haven't had any other reports of issues with the latest excon (but there was a version 2-3 ago that had some issues). You may also have luck with the very latest (if you weren't already on it prior to downgrading).